# Slab キャッシュの nfs_inode_cache が増加する原因を知りたい

Tags: linux

Slabキャッシュがメモリを圧迫していたので、以下のページを参考に
`echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` を実行すると、メモリ使用率が85％から30％にまで下がります。
しかし2日と経てば再びメモリ使用率85％に達してしまうので、原因を調査したいのですがどう調査したらいいのか分かりません。

[サーバーのメモリが少しずつ圧迫される原因と対策を調べてみた - Qiita](https://qiita.com/bezeklik/items/7e1ac9e5da39261be7bd)

**slabtopの実行結果**

[image: slabtopを実行した結果]

「nfs_inode_cache」について増加している原因を知りたく、検索しても「dentry」について記述してるサイトばかりで結論が出ませんでした。

Comment: 可能であれば実行環境の詳しい情報 (OSの種類やバージョン、カーネルバージョン等) を追記してみてください。 / 使用量が増えることによって、何か不都合は生じていますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RHELでのバグ](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/64667) に該当しない限り、NFS inode キャッシュがメモリに空きがあればサイズが大きくなるのは正常動作のうちで、メモリに空きが無くなってきたら通常はキャッシュから回収されるそうです。

手動でキャッシュサイズを小さくするには、NFSのファイルシステムをリマウントし直すか、既に試された drop_caches に値を書き込む方法もありますが、特に後者はシステム全体に影響を与える可能性があるので注意が必要とのこと。

他にもいくつかのパラメータで調整を行う方法はあるが、アプリのハングアップや頻繁なスワップ等が発生している状況でもない限り、デフォルト設定にしておくのが無難だそうです。

**参考:**
[nfs_inode_cache slab キャッシュが非常に大きくなる - Red Hat Customer Portal](https://access.redhat.com/ja/solutions/1174123)
[Unusually high nfs_inode_cache - Server fault](https://serverfault.com/q/605700/480984)